# get text oustside tags using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am very new to all this and am having a hard time getting specific text outside of any tags using BeautifulSoup.

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup('''
<li id="SalesRank" style="list-style : none">
    <b>Sellers Rank:</b> 
    #81 in Fun
    (<a href="http://www.google.com">See Top 100</a>)
</li>
''')


theRank = soup.find('li', attrs={'id':'SalesRank'}).find('b', text="Sellers Rank:")
print theRank.find_next_sibling().text.strip()
```

I am trying to get `#81 in Fun`

Comment: What output is your code giving you and what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The full text element after the `<b>` tag will include the `(` opening parenthesis.

Use the [`.next_sibling` attribute](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling) to get the next object from a given tag:

```
>>> soup.find('li', attrs={'id':'SalesRank'}).find('b', text="Sellers Rank:")
<b>Sellers Rank:</b>
>>> soup.find('li', attrs={'id':'SalesRank'}).find('b', text="Sellers Rank:").next_sibling
u' \n    #81 in Fun\n    ('
```